# semaphores in visual C++

Tags: c++-cli, semaphore

I am a new CLI learning. I need to modify a program to print out specific sequence. Please give me some guidelines. It is a Homework, I do NOT want people give me the answer. I really only want some guidelines.

I need to modify a given code using semaphores to print out this sequence AA/111\BA/356\YZ/654\JK/257\HG/445\…….

I am giving the following code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

ref class PrintTasks
{
public: static bool runFlag = true;

public:
void PrintDigit(Object^ name) {
    while (runFlag) {
        Console::WriteLine((String^)name);
    }
}

void PrintLetter(Object^ name) {
    while (runFlag) {
        Console::WriteLine((String^)name);
    }
}

void PrintSlashes(Object^ name) {
    while (runFlag) {
        Console::WriteLine("/");
        Console::WriteLine("\\");
    }
}
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
PrintTasks ^tasks = gcnew PrintTasks();
array<Thread^> ^threads = gcnew array<Thread^>(37);
// create 10 digit threads
for (int d=0; d<10; d++) {
    threads[d] = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintDigit ) );
    threads[d]->Start(d.ToString());
}
// create 26 letter threads
for (wchar_t d='A'; d<='Z'; d++) {
    threads[10+d-'A'] = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintLetter ) );
    threads[10+d-'A']->Start(d.ToString());
}
// create the slash thread
threads[36] = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintSlashes ) );
threads[36]->Start("");
// Let the threads to run for a period of time
Thread::Sleep(1000);
PrintTasks::runFlag=false;
// Aabort the threads
for (int i=0; i<37; i++) threads[i]->Abort();

return 0;
}
```

I did modification the code and the following is my version. One thing which I don't understand is the **digit** threads are created by a for-loop, the for-loop has to run completely in order to run the **letter** thread. Am I right?

```
// ThreadSync.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
 using namespace System::Threading;


ref class PrintTasks
{
public: static bool runFlag = true;

public:
void PrintDigit(Object^ name) {
    while (runFlag) {
        Console::WriteLine((String^)name);
        my_Semaphore1->WaitOne();
    }
}

void PrintLetter(Object^ name) {
    while (runFlag) {
        Console::WriteLine((String^)name);
        my_Semaphore2->WaitOne();
    }
}

void PrintSlashes(Object^ name) {
    while (runFlag) {
        Console::WriteLine("/");
        my_Semaphore1->Release();
        my_Semaphore1->Release();
        Console::WriteLine("\\");
        my_Semaphore2->Release();
        my_Semaphore2->Release();
        my_Semaphore2->Release();
    }
}

private: static Semaphore ^my_Semaphore1;
private: static Semaphore ^my_Semaphore2;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

Semaphore ^my_Semaphore1 = gcnew Semaphore(0,2);
Semaphore ^my_Semaphore2 = gcnew Semaphore(0,3);

PrintTasks ^tasks = gcnew PrintTasks();
array<Thread^> ^threads = gcnew array<Thread^>(37);
// create 10 digit threads
for (int d=0; d<10; d++) {
    threads[d] = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintDigit ) );
    threads[d]->Start(d.ToString());
}
// create 26 letter threads
for (wchar_t d='A'; d<='Z'; d++) {
    threads[10+d-'A'] = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintLetter ) );
    threads[10+d-'A']->Start(d.ToString());
}
// create the slash thread
threads[36] = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintSlashes ) );
threads[36]->Start("");
// Let the threads to run for a period of time
Thread::Sleep(1000);
PrintTasks::runFlag=false;
// Aabort the threads
for (int i=0; i<37; i++) threads[i]->Abort();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, for as far as I can see there is no reason for your statement to be false. The code creates 37 threads but runs in one. But since you still seem to have questions, please add them.

Comment: Static fields my_Semaphore1 and my_Semaphore2 don't initialized properly.